# Can I use collated deck screws with regular drill?

Tags: flooring, drill, subfloor

It seems that the screws are only sold collated - Simpson Strong-Tie. The driver tool is like $500. Can I just use a regular drill?  I wish to better attach my subfloor before putting down underlayment.

Comment: Should be able to, unless they use special made drive opening in the screw head.  If they use regular drives(square, torx, phillpes) then just need to undo the screws, same as collated nails can be used with a regular hammer.

Comment: Why not just buy something similar you can get loose? A screw really has only so many options.

Comment: Screwing down a sub floor usually does not need special screws, not like structural wood members, where you want greater weight(shear) holding.  Those screws and driver are made for the people who do this 6 days a week all year long, not for us doing it for an hour or two every ten years.

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info) (about your proposed solution rather than the actual problem). I suggest asking about the problem, which seems to be finding the right screws.

Comment: If you know how to use regular drill, you can. Remember before the expensive driver tools were invented, we only had regular drill.

Comment: "I suggest asking about the problem". 
Okay - good idea. I am screwing down a) 5/8" plywood underlayment onto 5/8" subfloor, and  b) screwing 5/8" plywood underlayment onto furring strips above 5/8" subfloor.

Comment: @Ruskes   Before drills we had manual screwdrivers.  Just think of doing a sub floor like that.

Comment: Your question will get much more useful answers if you specify the screws rather than us expecting to read your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Go buy your screws in a box or tub.  I assure you that screws are not only sold for use in automatic screw guns.  Any drill/driver will work for what you are doing.

Collated screws are sold that way to work in a gun by professionals for whom the time savings justifies the expense.  You don't buy nails sold to work in nailers if you're just using a hammer.